# How do I calculate the acceptance criterion for configuration bias sampling of my polymer?

Tags: monte-carlo, polymers

I am running a lattice simulation of a single chain polymer on a lattice with every other site occupied by solvent. The additional wrinkle is that every particle on the lattice has a number/spin orientation associated with it, which is subject to change throughout the simulation. There are $Z$ spins possible for every particle. The range of interaction is a nearest-neighbor interaction. Two particles cannot occupy the same site.
\begin{align}
&\mathcal{H} = \sum _{(i,j)} \epsilon _{ij} \\
&\epsilon_{ij} =
\begin{cases}
\epsilon ^a, \text{ if spins at locations $i, j$ are the same }\\
\epsilon^n, \text{ if spins at locations $i, j$ spins are not the same}
\end{cases} 
\end{align}
where $(i,j)$ are two lattice sites which are nearest neighbor to one another. Once I plant a polymer on such a lattice and fill up every other site on the lattice with solvent, I want to sample this system. How do I perform polymer configuration moves, such as configurational bias chain regrowth (CBCR)? This is how I would run CBCR if I did not have solvent:

1. Pick a uniformly random monomer on the chain.
2. Pick a side where you want to regrow polymer.
3. Regrow polymer one monomer at a time. Calculate all the possible energetic states of the monomer per Rosenbluth sampling.
4. Include Rosenbluth weights in acceptance criterion.

But how do I do this type of regrowth if I have a lattice full of solvent? Every time I go to a new spot, I have to displace a solvent molecule. How do I account for the fact that every move involves some sort of solvent displacement. If required, I can give more explanation of the system I am performing.

I would appreciate any advice you have for me!

Answer (score 2):

From my little experience I would start by defining a spin value for "this site has solvent instead of polymer". (It could replace your existing "no polymer here" spin value, or be a new one if you really expect voids without either polymer or solvent.)

From there you can just do standard lattice statistical mechanics. How does a solvent-ed site "feel" about being next to other solvent-ed sites? Next to polymer sites? Being flipped into a polymer site? Well, all those will be encoded in $\epsilon_{ij}$ neighbour terms and $\mu_i$ field terms. If your terms are well-chosen, you should have a reasonable model.

Comment: Beautiful! It's great to have another polymer expert here to answer these questions!